# how to use onChange on array of objects to add data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am new in ReactJS world,
I want to update my useState hook which contains array of objects, but it is now updating the data according to my requirement
please help me in this.

**ContactForm.js**

```
function ContactForm() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const submitForm = () => {
    console.log(user);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        onChange={(e) =>
          setUser((state) => [...state, { user_name: e.target.value }])
        }
        value={user.user_name}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="mobile"
        onChange={(e) =>
          setUser([...user, [...user, { mobile_number: e.target.value }]])
        }
        value={user.mobile_number}
      />
      <button onClick={submitForm}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am expecting something like

```
[{
    user_name:"abc",
    mobile_number:"123"
}]
```

should be store in my state, but I am getting some different output like below

```
0: {user_name: "a"}
1: {user_name: "as"}
2: {user_name: "asd"}
3: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
4: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, Array(4), {…}]
5: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, Array(4), Array(5), {…}]
```

please help me out from this issue, and please tell me how objects in an array in useState worked
Thanks in advance

**(updated stack)**
I tried so many ways, that's why you may feel what I have written in code, especially in the

```
<input/>
```

tag

Comment: `[...user, [...user,` you are adding your previous values as an array instead of just spreading the previous values into the array itself, you should have it like you have the previous one

Comment: hi @PatrickEvans , I tried with a single [...user also, but still I was getting same issue

Comment: Though, it's unclear why you're even using an array here.

Comment: hi @EmileBergeron , i want to store data in objects of array format so i can apply .map() on it

Comment: Are you meaning to just have a single user or multiple users? If single your state should be an object instead of an array. If you want multiple users you need to make the single user object first and use some other method to add it to your array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your code, I'm guessing `user` is an object instead of an array. You are initializing the user as an array even though it should be an object (assuming from the use of `user` word here, i.e singular). I made the following changes:-

1. Initialize user as an object.
2. Use spread operator and add new property `user_name` or `mobile_number` as needed to update the state.

The below code should work

```js
function ContactForm() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const submitForm = () => {
    console.log(user);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="name"
        onChange={(e) =>
          setUser({...user, user_name: e.target.value });
        }
        value={user.user_name}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="mobile"
        onChange={(e) =>
          setUser({...user, mobile_number: e.target.value })
        }
        value={user.mobile_number}
      />
      <button onClick={submitForm}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks @utkarsh , now it is totally working file

Comment: just tell me, what happened when i put my object inside an array??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your setState on the mobile input. Right now you're spreading the user as an array when you want it to be an object. When you do [...user] inside of the parent array, you create a new array instead of an object. Also, you need to make sure to edit the last element of the array. So:

```
setUser([...user, {...user[user.length], mobile_number: e.target.value }])
```

The parentheses get the last element of that array, not sure if that's what you're looking for. Pretty sure you need some way to identify which object in the array you want to use when editing the mobile number.